# What is the exact syntax of a postgres tsquery?

Tags: postgresql

To generate a tsquery containing user input, I want to know the syntax for it so I can properly escape anything that needs escaping. But the postgresql documentation does not give a precise definition of what a valid tsquery looks like, as far as I can find. Does anyone know?

Comment: You want something more detailed than this? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSQUERY ?

Comment: Yes. Those docs don't list for example which characters are interpreted as operators (only those mentioned or all punctuation?), and which characters can form lexemes (the parser is configurable, so I guess in principle anything?). And is there any kind of escape within quotes, or can quotes just not be part of a lexeme?

Comment: @JanKanis "*Quoting rules for lexemes are the same as described previously for lexemes in `tsvector`*". And there it says "*To represent lexemes containing whitespace or punctuation, surround them with quotes*", so I guess that refers to *all* punctuation.